# Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x111189058) to 'NSString' error

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use the amount_wallet in

```
func getDistrictList() -> Void {
        let reachable = Reachability()!
        let tempDict = NSMutableDictionary()
        let user = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "user_data") as! NSDictionary
        tempDict.setValue(user.object(forKey:"user_id")!, forKey: "user_id")
        tempDict.setValue(AppDelegate.appDelegateObject().languageToSend(), forKey: "lang_code")

        if reachable.isReachable {
            Services.requestForUpdatedWallet(postDic: tempDict, completion: { (result) in
                let isSuccess = result["success"] as! Bool
                if isSuccess {




                    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                        if result["wallet_amount"] != nil {
                            self.labelWallet.text = "\(AppDelegate.appDelegateObject().localLanguage(key: "available_money", comment: "")) \(result["wallet_amount"] as! String) €"
                            self.stringWallet = result["wallet_amount"] as! String
                        }else{
                            self.labelWallet.text = "\(AppDelegate.appDelegateObject().localLanguage(key: "available_money", comment: "")) 0 €"
                            self.stringWallet = "0"
                        }
                        MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDs(for: self.view, animated: true)
                       // self.tblDistrict.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
//        else{
//            self.showAlert(title: AppDelegate.appDelegateObject().localLanguage(key: "app_name", comment: ""), message: AppDelegate.appDelegateObject().localLanguage(key: "no_internet", comment: ""))
//        }
    }
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

But it says Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x111189058) to 'NSString' error

What is the right way of casting a umber to string?

Thanks
Somdeb

Comment: There at least 6 questions about the same error message in the "Related" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
self.stringWallet = result["wallet_amount"] as! String
```

with

```
if let value = result["wallet_amount"] as? NSNumber {
  self.stringWallet = value.stringValue
}
```

and any casting line with same value ,  as the type of `wallet_amount` value is `NSNumber` not `String`

Comment: Its perfect Thank you Very much

Comment: This has been asked and answered so often ...